# How to get elapsed day in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
SELECT 
  TRANSACTION_ID,
  (SELECT CASE WHEN CLOSE_DATE = NULL 
    THEN
      round(sysdate - created_date) 
    ELSE ROUND(CLOSE_DATE - CREATED_DATE)
  ) as NODAYS 
FROM TBL_TRANSACTION 
WHERE CREATED_BY = 101913
```

Comment: What happens when you run this - what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `select`, you're missing an `end`, and you can't test for `null` with equality operators - `null` is never equal to, or not equal to, anything, even itself.

This will get you further:

```
SELECT 
  TRANSACTION_ID,
  CASE
    WHEN CLOSE_DATE IS NULL 
    THEN round(sysdate - created_date) 
    ELSE ROUND(CLOSE_DATE - CREATED_DATE)
  END as NODAYS 
FROM TBL_TRANSACTION 
WHERE CREATED_BY = 101913
```

You could use `NVL()` to simplify this a little:

```
SELECT TRANSACTION_ID,
  ROUND(NVL(CLOSE_DATE, SYSDATE) - CREATED_DATE) as NODAYS 
FROM TBL_TRANSACTION 
WHERE CREATED_BY = 101913
```

Comment: `NVL` should be on `CLOSE_DATE`.